# Set Variables for Airflow during Helm install

Tags: kubernetes, airflow, kubernetes-helm, kind

I'm installing Airflow on `kind` with the following command:

```
export RELEASE_NAME=first-release
export NAMESPACE=airflow

helm install $RELEASE_NAME apache-airflow/airflow --namespace $NAMESPACE \
    --set images.airflow.repository=my-dags \
    --set images.airflow.tag=0.0.1 \
    --values env.yaml
```

Andthe file `env.yaml` looks like the below:

```yaml
env:
  - name: "AIRFLOW_VAR_KEY"
    value: "value_1"
```

But from the Web UI (when I go to Admins --> Variables), these credentials don't appear there.

How do I pass these credentials during `helm install`? Thanks!

**UPDATE:** It turns out that the environment variable was set successfully. However it doesn't show up on the Web UI

Comment: it is supposed with `--values` or `-f` just as fine: https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_install/#helm-install

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure how your full **env.yaml** file is

but to set the environment variables in Airflow

```
## environment variables for the web/scheduler/worker Pods (for airflow configs)
  ##
  ## WARNING:
  ## - don't include sensitive variables in here, instead make use of `airflow.extraEnv` with Secrets
  ## - don't specify `AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN`, `AIRFLOW__CELERY__RESULT_BACKEND`,
  ##   or `AIRFLOW__CELERY__BROKER_URL`, they are dynamically created from chart values
  ##
  ## NOTE:
  ## - airflow allows environment configs to be set as environment variables
  ## - they take the form: AIRFLOW__<section>__<key>
  ## - see the Airflow documentation: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/howto/set-config.html
  ##
  ## EXAMPLE:
  ##   config:
  ##     ## Security
  ##     AIRFLOW__CORE__SECURE_MODE: "True"
  ##     AIRFLOW__API__AUTH_BACKEND: "airflow.api.auth.backend.deny_all"
```

[Reference file](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/airflow/values.yaml#L44)

and after that you have to run your command and further your **DAG** will be able to access the variables.

Helm documentation : https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/airflow#docs-airflow---configs

Make sure you are configuring section : **airflow.config**

Comment: I don't think [this](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/airflow#docs-airflow---configs) is refering to the same helm chart  as [this](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/helm-chart/stable/airflow-configuration.html)

Comment: if you look at the README file of the chart you provided, you'll see it says "THIS CHART HAS MOVED". And it is the community version. I'm using the official Airflow helm chart.

Comment: can you share link which you are using ?

Comment: I was using this one: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/helm-chart/stable/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I've figured this one out: The environment variables are set just nicely on the pods. However, this will not appear on the Web UI.

Workaround: to make it appear in the web UI, I will have to go into the Scheduler pod and import the variables. It can be done with a bash script.

```sh
# Get the name of scheduler pod
export SCHEDULER_POD_NAME="$(kubectl get pods --no-headers -o custom-columns=":metadata.name" -n airflow | grep scheduler)"
# Copy variables to the scheduler pod
kubectl cp ./variables.json airflow/$SCHEDULER_POD_NAME:./
# Import variables to scheduler with airflow command
kubectl -n $NAMESPACE exec $SCHEDULER_POD_NAME -- airflow variables import variables.json
```