# Set AirFlow Variables and Connections during Helm install

Tags: airflow, kubernetes-helm, airflow-scheduler

With the [official Helm charts](https://github.com/apache/airflow/tree/main/chart) for AirFlow, is it possible to set the `Variable` and the `Connection` which will also appear in the AirFlow UI.
[image: Variables in AirFlow]
I found a few workarounds:

- by setting the environment variable `AIRFLOW_VAR_<variable_name>`. This can be used with the syntax `Variable.get('variable_name')` but it does not appear in the AirFlow UI.
- Running a bash script which will import the variables from a .json file as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70286033/2542835). But it seems to be a hacky solution.

The official helm charts of AirFlow have a [lot of options](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/chart/values.yaml), but unfortunately I could not find one for the Variables and the Connections. Also, please note that I am using the [AirFlow provided official Helm charts](https://github.com/apache/airflow/tree/main/chart). The community charts of AirFlow has this option [here](https://github.com/airflow-helm/charts/blob/main/charts/airflow/values.yaml#L143).

Comment: Are you setting the environment variables in with the `extraEnv` value in your `values.yaml`? Does it appear in the container environment?

Comment: I tried setting it with `extraEnv`. Unfortunately, it does not appear in the AirFlow UI. I can set a variable such as `AIRFLOW_VAR_key='value'` with it, but it will not appear in the UI

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, even if the environment variables are set correctly they don`t appear in the UI.  For checking the values have been set correctly I created a small DAG that extracts and prints the values.  Give that a try.

tip. import os and then use the os.environ() function.

Answer (score 0):

The [values.yaml](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/chart/values.yaml) that you mentioned has `secret` and `extraSecret` sections which you can use. You'll need to create a yaml file called `override.yaml` to override values under these sections of the `values.yaml`.

Example:

```
# override.yaml

secret:
  - envName: "AIRFLOW_CONN_GCP"
    secretName: "my-airflow-connections"
    secretKey: "AIRFLOW_CONN_GCP"
  - envName: "my-env"
    secretName: "my-secret-name"
    secretKey: "my-secret-key"

extraSecrets:
  my-airflow-connections:
    data: |
      AIRFLOW_CONN_GCP: 'base64_encoded_gcp_conn_string'
  my-secret-name:
    stringData: |
      my-secret-key: my-secret
```

You can read more about it in the [docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/helm-chart/stable/adding-connections-and-variables.html).

Comment: Hey Elad. I am looking for a way by which it also appears on the AirFlow UI. Correct me if I am wrong, but by setting the `AIRFLOW_VAR_key` or `AIRFLOW_CONN_key`, the values will not appear in the UI. Correct?

Comment: What is the difference between `secrets` and `extraSecrets` ?

Comment: @VikramadityaGaonkar Did you found a way that it appears in Airflow UI?

Comment: There's a note in the documentation here: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/connection.html#uri-format-example stating that "Connections defined in environment variables will not show up in the Airflow UI or using airflow connections list."